# Change ShowCoordinates format to WebMercator

Tags: sharepoint-2010, silverlight-5.0, arcgis

I would like to extend ShowCoordinates behavior to show the coordinates in WebMercator format.

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/silverlight-api/samples/start.htm#ShowCoordinatesBehavior

I tried to create new Behavior by inheriting ShowCoordinates but failed to convert the format.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this tutorial instead:

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/silverlight-api/samples/start.htm#MouseCoords

I personally find the way the coordinates follow the mouse cursor around on the one you were looking at to be frustrating.  This one displays them in a box.  However, the advantage is that rather than being a behaviour, it's handled in code behind.  Therefore you can modify the format of the coordinates to your desire.

Also if you want to display the coordinates as a geographic lat/long then have a look at the WebMercator class in the API which has methods to convert between projected and geographic coordinates:

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/silverlight-api/apiref/ESRI.ArcGIS.Client~ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Projection.WebMercator.html